# Getting epoc time in c++(hexadecimal value printed implicitly)

Tags: c++, time, epoch

My program want to print epoc time in C++

If I print with fprintf/printf command, i get the correct output

```
fprintf(stdout, "epoch time=%u\t", (unsigned)time(NULL));
printf("var epoch=%u\n",(unsigned)time(NULL));
```

***Output--->1528573149***

But When i print the epoc time using C++, the output it is printed in **"hex"** format

```
cout<<"epoch time ="<< (unsigned)time(0);
```

Output---->5b1c2cdd

Unable to figure, how decimal value is implicitly converted to hexadecimal value.

Comment: Does it *matter*? Regardless of base, it's still the same number..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shows up as decimal for me, but try this:

```
std::cout << std::dec << (unsigned)time(0);
```

Or you can set desired format flag:

```
std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::dec, std::ios_base::basefield);
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way this:

```
cout<<"epoch time ="<< (unsigned)time(0);
```

could print in hexadecimal is if you've previously set `std::cout` to hexadecimal mode.

For example:

```
#include <ctime>              
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    std::cout << "    decimal epoch time = " << time(0) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::hex;
    std::cout << "hexadecimal epoch time = " << time(0) << "\n";
}
```

The output on my system is:

```
    decimal epoch time = 1528663129
hexadecimal epoch time = 5b1d8c59
```

This is in my opinion the most annoying feature of C++ I/O: To print a single item with a non-default format, you have to change the state of the output stream, which affects all later output on that stream.

If you want to print a single data item in hexadecimal (which you've probably done earlier in your program), you can do something like:

```
std::cout << "x = " << std::hex << x << std::dec << "\n";
```

This sets the output format back to decimal -- regardless of what it was previously. There's probably a complicated way to restore it to whatever it was.

Comment: i like the explanation given!! +1